# Method called when keyboard gets hidden

Tags: android, android-layout

When I am writing into an `EditText` and the device has soft home/back buttons, the back buttons becomes an arrow pointing down meaning "hide the keyboard". What method is called when that button is pressed? I tried `Activity.onBackPressed` but it's not the method I'm looking for.

Comment: See my comment on the answer from Gabe Sechan.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing.  There is no notification for keyboard hidden.

Comment: So how can I make an `EditText` lose focus when keyboard is hidden?

Comment: @GabeSechan: Are you sure about that? Showing / hiding a keyboard is considered a configuration change. Specifying `android:configChanges="keyboard"` for an `Activity` in the manifest should mean that `Activity.onConfigurationChanged(...)` will be called when a keyboard is shown or hidden.